# W10 Pro wont play DVD using VLC or any other software, why?

Tags: vlc-media-player, dvd

Ive got a DVD im trying to play on a laptop that has a DVD drive via VLC, the laptop is running W10 Pro.

When i try to play the DVD i get an error, please see error message and log file output in screenshot below.

At first i thought it might be a faulty disk, so i tried another, but to no avail.

I also thought it may be a faulty DVD drive, so i tested using an external drive, but this did not work either.

[image]

Comment: What region is the disk?  Set the log verbosity to 2 and attempt to play the video then update the question to include the information from the log.  Are you using "File item" or "Open disk item"?  Move the file off any network share for the time being, use a path as that as short as possible, then try playing the file.  [**I suspect the file path is simply to long.**](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=147260)

Comment: Also, you may need digital rights management (DRM) installed and enabled for some videos.

Comment: @Ramhound , ive changed the logging mode of VLC to "warning" level and it gave me the following, see paste bin here : https://pastebin.com/eBDUCSgE . The disc is region 2 and i am in Europe (UK) on a UK machine, so it should work. To open the DVD im locating it in windows explore and right clicking and using "play with VLC media player". Ive put the disc back in the internal drive, but no change. Not sure i understand your comment about the network share, the external DVD drive was USB. Here is the updated screenshot from VLC with messages at level 2 : https://imgur.com/a/FeBTTw3